# How do I match a single descendent (like $.find()) without searching through the rest of the DOM tree after it's found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery and JQuery mobile, and unfortunately I need to use the $.find() method quite a bit to search all the descendants of an element.

Many times, I know that there will only be one result. But the find method will keep going through the whole tree after finding what might be a very early match. Your first thought might be that I should just navigate to where I expect element to be, but this truly is impossible for some of my queries.

Is there any way to do a full descendent search like $.find() that stops searching after identifying the first match?

Comment: Yes, use document.querySelector to select elements rather than jQuery. It uses the same css selector syntax (minus some jQuery only functionality) and returns only the first that was found. Whether or not it actually stops at the first will depend on how the browser being used implemented it.

Comment: Also, jQuery doesn't actually iterate over all descendants unless your selector can only be selected in that way (for example if you used a jQuery selector that isn't implemented in css). Otherwise, jQuery uses document.querySelector which uses the browser's css selector engine.

Comment: To make your search for elements go faster you'll need to know something intuitive about the DOM structure you're searching. If you can make assumptions like, `a` elements will always be a child of `b` elements, then you can use `.children()`/`.siblings()`/`.next()`/etc... which search for elements in a more focused scope.

Comment: @KevinB - it would be helpful to have this as an answer, with some examples on how it works. A jsperf would be awesome too, to show the difference in speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what your selector is. Unless you are using a jquery specific selector or a selector such as `.someclass`, `#someid`, or `div`, jquery passes the selector directly to `element.querySelectorAll()` which uses the browser's selector engine to do the work. Therefore, jquery is not iterating over all the elements, meaning there is no way to make it *"stop"* when it finds the first one, it's going to find them all then give you them all. You could instead use `element.querySelector()` and skip jQuery to have the browser return only the first match, but whether or not that is significantly faster will depend on how the browser implements those methods. (it will always be somewhat faster simply due to not using jQuery, but looking at a jsperf it looks like it's generally faster to use `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll`)

Now, when it comes to selectors that DO include jQuery only selectors, simply omit those jquery only selectors from your `.find` and instead use them in a `.filter` so that you'll use the more efficient `element.querySelectorAll()` first, then filter only the results by the jQuery only selector.

For example, `.find(".foo:button")` would be more efficiently written as `.find(".foo").filter(":button")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.querySelector

http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementbyid/35

jQuery isn't being used in the jsperf, but since the way jQuery selects elements relies heavily on the same methods being used in the jsperf, I think it is relevant. a jQuery selector selecting by id vs one selecting by class for example should see about the same difference in performance as seen between `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`.

**Also,**
There is currently a feature request open for a method that would automatically make this switch for you: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11785 it's held up because it doesn't appear to actually cause a significant performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your selector specific enough, and use the first method.

```
$('yourselector').first()
```

Or if you already know how that the result will be at most one, you could actually decorate this special element in the dom with an ID or with a class that is somewhat unique.

Remember that CSS searches are performed from "right to left" the order specified by your selector, so it will actually stop faster than you might think.

It all depends on how specific your CSS selector is.

Comment: :first is a jquery extension - it doesn't actually stop the search. Please read the notes in http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Can you use .first()?

```
$('tag').first()
```

http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: This still selects all of the 'tag' elements, then only plucks one off the top.